# What are the Console2 command line options? Launch new tab versus new window

Tags: visual-studio-2012, console2, external-tools

The help file for Console2 isn't opening on my Win8 or Win7 VM and I'm looking to see what command line options it supports.

Basically I have integrated it a bit with Visual Studio as a 'External' tool with this command...

```
Command: C:\Program Files (x86)\Console2\Console.exe
Arguments: -d "$(ProjectDir)"
Initial directory: $(ProjectDir)
```

But it launches a new window every time.  I was hoping to make it launch a new window **only** if Console2 isn't running, otherwise simply open a new **tab**.

Comment: Right-click the help file, choose *Properties*, and then click the *Unblock* button at the bottom of the dialog.

Comment: VS makes no attempt to keep track of started tools.  Use Alt+Tab.

Comment: @HansPassant That doesn't help much when I want it to have Console2 opened to current project path.  Additionally, it is often the app itself (i.e. Console2) that can check for previously running instances of itself and make it behave properly.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks, will try that and see what command line options I have available to me.